# Problemas com Input AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou com um problema na minha aplicação.

Quando uso o `ng-repeat` do `angularJS` para criar uma tabela, e nessa tabela existe um `input`, e nesse campo `input`, vem preenchido com um valor.

Tem também um botão SALVAR, onde ele pega o valor do `INPUT` e manda como parâmetro.

Aí que está o problema. Se eu não clicar no `Input` para depois clicar no salvar, ele não envia nenhum valor.

Alguém tem uma idéia ?

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app='app-pedido'>
  <div ng-controller='ctl-pedido'>
    <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Código</th>
          <th>Descrição</th>
          <th>Quantidade</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='ax in itens'>
          <td>{{ax.codigo}}</td>
          <td>{{ax.descricao}}</td>
          <td><input class='form-control' type='number' ng-model='txtQuantidade' ng-value='ax.quantidade'></td>
          <td><button ng-click='Salvar(ax.codigo, txtQuantidade)' type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Salvar</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
angular.module('app-pedido', [])

.controller('ctl-pedido', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.itens = [{
    codigo: '00002305',
    descricao: 'Módulo de Memória',
    quantidade: '10.00'
  }];

  $scope.Salvar = function(codigo, quantidade) {

  alert('O código do produto é ' + codigo + ' e a quantidade é ' + quantidade);

  };

});
```

Veja [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/1v0v5ns2/3/) o exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Você está usando um form com post ou está enviado os dados via json?

Comment: Enviando os dados via JSON.

O problema é exatamente o que está acontecendo no jsfiddle.

O Valor só é passado no parâmetro caso eu "entre" no input. Aí Funciona.

Comment: Troque o tipo do input para text, retirei o ng-value, coloquei o ng-model referenciando a quantidade que está no ax: https://jsfiddle.net/1v0v5ns2/13/

Comment: Perfeito!

Você saberia explicar o por que o type number não funciona?

Comment: Vou pesquisar e coloco como resposta. Tem um mais detalhe, você pode editar a quantidade, e passar a lista toda como json que o angular passa os valores atualizados. Eu tenho uma lista parecida em um sistema, onde o usuário pode editar a quantidade de vários itens.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer dessa maneira que você me falou.

Eu sou iniciante com AngularJS, tenho um pouco de dificuldades, mas a sua ideia é no caso para alterar em lote, todos itens de uma só vez.

É isso né?

Comment: Não, você pode ter um lote e quer alterar apenas um.

Comment: @GuilhermeCatini o `type=number` funciona... se tu lhe deres um `number`: https://jsfiddle.net/1v0v5ns2/21/

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

No input da quantidade você precisa passar

ax.quantidade no ng-model

```
<input class='form-control' type='number' ng-model='ax.quantidade' ng-value='ax.quantidade'>
```

e na função click você tem que passar ax.quantidade, que no caso é o valor do objeto que esta sendo executado e gerado no for naquele momento.

```
<button ng-click='Salvar(ax.codigo, ax.quantidade)' type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Salvar</button>
```

Da forma que esta feito você esta passando uma variavel txtQuantidade que não é inicializada com nenhum valor.

Veja seu exemplo funcionando.

https://jsfiddle.net/boLsq2ua/1/

Answer (score 0):

Existe um problema com bind do Angular, quando o tipo do `input` é `number`. Pelo que pesquisei não existe uma resposta exata para o por que do problema.

Você pode contornar isso mudando o tipo do `input` para `text`, que foi o que eu fiz. O Exemplo está aqui: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1v0v5ns2/13/) ou você pode criar uma diretiva para fazer o parse do número para int ou float conforme essa resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395188/angular-validate-input-type-number

Tem uma thread de discussão desse assunto em um fórum do Angular: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/Ecjx2fo8Qvk/x6iNlZrO_mwJ

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está utilizando o `ng-model` para um valor temporário, quando na realidade deveria ser a propriedade que deve espelhar o valor do `input`:

```js
angular
  .module('app-pedido', [])
  .controller('ctl-pedido', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.itens = [{
      codigo: '00002305',
      descricao: 'Módulo de Memória',
      quantidade: '10.00'
    }];

    $scope.Salvar = function(item) {
      alert('O código do produto é ' + item.codigo + ' e a quantidade é ' + item.quantidade);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='app-pedido'>
  <div ng-controller='ctl-pedido'>
    <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Código</th>
          <th>Descrição</th>
          <th>Quantidade</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='ax in itens'>
          <td>{{ax.codigo}}</td>
          <td>{{ax.descricao}}</td>
          <td>{{ax.quantidade}}</td>
          <td><input class='form-control' type='number' ng-model='ax.quantidade'></td>
          <td><button ng-click='Salvar(ax)' type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Salvar</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Não precisa trocar o tipo do seu input.
Troque o seu código de:

```
<tr ng-repeat='ax in itens'>
```

para:

```
<tr ng-repeat='ax in itens' ng-init="txtQuantidade= ax.quantidade">
```